# Javascript fails to load from particular domains in OS X Snow Leopard on all browsers

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, google-chrome, javascript

The error appears universal for Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc. I have repaired permissions, cleaned any caches I could find and so forth but the problem remains.

The problem appears also with externally loaded jQuery (for instance), returning in the case of jQuery the following errors:

```
$ is not defined (Firefox)

or

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (Chrome)
```

Examples for websites that fail to load/run JS: reddit, omegle, www.translation-telephone.com.

What are some things I should try?

Comment: Check the source code to see where the sites load their jQuery from, then `ping` these hosts or use `curl` to retrieve the jQuery files in Terminal. If it fails, you should get a useful error message. Have you checked web developer extension (Firefox) or Safari's Develop menu for resource tracking functionality that could also provide some information?

Comment: Reddit uses ajax.googleapis.com to load the jQuery js.